# Can't convert curl to python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I copied request as CURL with help of dev-tools and received:

```
curl 'https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCommunities' \
  -H 'authority: ok.ru' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'strd: false' \
  -H 'ok-screen: searchResult' \
  -H 'content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'tkn: eezDYrXx08aiDcsqCCCheb1fGdGIvuJ9' \
  -H 'origin: https://ok.ru' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://ok.ru/' \
  -H 'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'cookie: bci=5639450919803662892; _statid=72da67cb-c979-4442-948d-b76b70d16b59; tmr_lvid=2ac18e93052a4516697406103a6db5b3; tmr_lvidTS=1575669087459; msg_conf=2468555756792551; _flashVersion=0; cudr=0; klos=0; AUTHCODE=EjUzQb4TKlF4mTbJklDGt-dg-65th4TTwrbLdAPrK8mvgyWCFTIdNoeMcBkVrvZruEBK9frXso45DCrvoq8K9p-7ZUcDvASmGvV13LQ5gxgls-AFQjI7ZEPmb6u08TLFJ57ZCb4R00LhHto_3; JSESSIONID=a381dc641575389c384c9c7eacd747d14853670edfe4c807.f00f63fb; LASTSRV=ok.ru; viewport=762; TZ=6; CDN=; nbp=; tmr_detect=1%7C1605813256183; tmr_reqNum=495; TZD=6.683; TD=683' \
  --data-binary $'{\n  "id": 38,\n  "parameters": {\n    "category": "UNIVERSITY",\n    "cityId": "10399843062",\n    "query": "Рос"\n  }\n}' \
  --compressed
```

Copied request to console (curl works fine). Received result

```
{"id":"38","success":true,"result":[{"id":"6100259920","category":"UNIVERSITY","name":"СПбГУКиТ, Санкт-Петербургский государственный университет кино и телевидения (бывш. ЛИКИ)","badgeName":"СПбГУКиТ"},{"id":"6098569210","category":"UNIVERSITY","name":"СПбГУЭФ (ФИНЭК), Санкт-Петербургский государственный университет экономики и финансов (бывш. ЛФЭИ им. Н.А. Вознесенского)","badgeName":"СПбГУЭФ (ФИНЭК)"},{"id":"6101852454","category":"UNIVERSITY","name":"СПбГУКИ, Санкт-Петербургский государственный университет культуры и искусств (бывш. ЛГИК им. Н.К. Крупской, СПбГАК)","badgeName":"СПбГУКИ"},{"id":"6096539930","category":"UNIVERSITY", ....
```

Converted curl to python requests with help of https://curl.trillworks.com/ Received:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'ok.ru',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'dnt': '1',
    'strd': 'false',
    'ok-screen': 'searchResult',
    'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
    'tkn': 'eezDYrXx08aiDcsqCCCheb1fGdGIvuJ9',
    'origin': 'https://ok.ru',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://ok.ru/',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cookie': 'bci=5639450919803662892; _statid=72da67cb-c979-4442-948d-b76b70d16b59; tmr_lvid=2ac18e93052a4516697406103a6db5b3; tmr_lvidTS=1575669087459; msg_conf=2468555756792551; _flashVersion=0; cudr=0; klos=0; AUTHCODE=EjUzQb4TKlF4mTbJklDGt-dg-65th4TTwrbLdAPrK8mvgyWCFTIdNoeMcBkVrvZruEBK9frXso45DCrvoq8K9p-7ZUcDvASmGvV13LQ5gxgls-AFQjI7ZEPmb6u08TLFJ57ZCb4R00LhHto_3; JSESSIONID=a381dc641575389c384c9c7eacd747d14853670edfe4c807.f00f63fb; LASTSRV=ok.ru; viewport=762; TZ=6; CDN=; nbp=; tmr_detect=1%7C1605813256183; tmr_reqNum=495; TZD=6.683; TD=683',
}

data = '${\\n "id": 38,\\n "parameters": {\\n "category": "UNIVERSITY",\\n "cityId": "10399843062",\\n "query": "\u0420\u043E\u0441"\\n }\\n}'

response = requests.post('https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCommunities', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.content)
```

Tried this code and received error

> Body is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

Added  .encode('utf-8'))

```
response = requests.post('https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCommunities', headers=headers, data=data.encode('utf-8'))
```

But received invalid result:

> b'{"success":false,"error":{"type":1,"typeName":"INVALID_REQUEST","errorCode":"api.invalid-format","errorMessage":"Invalid request format: Unrecognized token '$': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5399802b; line: 1, column: 3]"},"result":null}'

How can I receive valid result?

```
{"id":"38","success":true,"result":[{"id":"6100259920","category":"UNIVERSITY","name":"СПбГУКиТ, Санкт-Петербургский государственный университет кино и телевидения (бывш. ЛИКИ)","badgeName":"СПбГУКиТ"},{"id":"6098569210","category":"UNIVERSITY","name":"СПбГУЭФ (ФИНЭК), Санкт-Петербургский государственный университет экономики и финансов (бывш. ЛФЭИ им. Н.А. Вознесенского)","badgeName":"СПбГУЭФ (ФИНЭК)"},
```

**UPDATE**

1. Tried to use data without $

   data = '{\n "id": 38,\n "parameters": {\n "category": "UNIVERSITY",\n "cityId": "10399843062",\n "query": "\u0420\u043E\u0441"\n }\n}'

Received error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 99-101: Body ('Рос') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

2. Tried

data = '{ "id": 38, "parameters": { "category": "UNIVERSITY", "cityId": "10399843062", "query": "\u0420\u043E\u0441" }}'

Received error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 89-91: Body ('Рос') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: The curl command has the dollar sign _outside_ of quotes: `--data-binary $'{...}'`, but the python code has the dollar sign _inside_ of quotes: `data = '${...}'`

Comment: Thank you. But it didn't help. See updates in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you accidentally copied the `$` into your python code. Try changing to this line:

```
data = '{\\n "id": 38,\\n "parameters": {\\n "category": "UNIVERSITY",\\n "cityId": "10399843062",\\n "query": "\u0420\u043E\u0441"\\n }\\n}'
```

You could even remove the `\n`'s:

```
data = '{ "id": 38, "parameters": { "category": "UNIVERSITY", "cityId": "10399843062", "query": "\u0420\u043E\u0441" }}'
```

---

### Edit

As for the

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 89-91: Body ('Рос') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

check out the end of [this forum](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1822)

```
a = "\u13E0\u19E0\u1320"
a.encode('latin1')  # Throws UnicodeEncodeError, proves that this can't be expressed in ISO-8859-1.
a.encode('utf-8')  # Totally fine.
```

So you could probably try something like:

```
data = '{ "id": 38, "parameters": { "category": "UNIVERSITY", "cityId": "10399843062", "query": "Poc" }}'
```

or

```
data = '{ "id": 38, "parameters": { "category": "UNIVERSITY", "cityId": "10399843062", "query": "\u0420\u043E\u0441" }}'
data = data.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you. But it didn't help. See updates in description

Comment: @mascai I changed the answer accordingly. Is this one better?

Comment: This did not work for Russian letters. This works only for english word "Рос". How can I fix it?

Comment: Hmm try the original one with ```\u0420\u043E\u0441``` but after ```data = '... ``` on a new line type ```data = data.encode('utf-8')```?